# VB.Net How to download url in javascript?

Tags: javascript, .net, hyperlink

How to get currrent link in javascript or after click to download button.

```html
  Dim HtmlColl As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
        For Each elem As HtmlElement In HtmlColl
            If elem.GetAttribute("id").Equals("downloadbtn") Then
                elem.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
```

**web source:**

```html
http://xsitex.com/lrqpbs6uyca0/url_javascr.jpg.html

<div class="download-button-block">
    <div class="clear"></div>
     <button id="downloadbtn" class="green-button">
      <span class="btext">Download file</span>
     </button>
   </div> <!--end right column-->
  </form>

<br><center>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--<![CDATA[
/* PLACEMENT: Setup.xsitex.com.xsitex.com_980x250 */
if(location.protocol.substr(0,4)=='http')document.write(unescape('%3C')+'script id="Setup.xsitex.com.xsitex.com_980x250" src="'+location.protocol+'//lv.adocean.pl/_'+(new Date()).getTime()+'/ad.js?id=SwaXpdclN776PUuiIkkTHSZPXg_FnPrrh06YBtN1u8X.M7/x='+screen.width+'/y='+screen.height+'" type="text/javascript"'+unescape('%3E%3C')+'/script'+unescape('%3E'));
//]]>--></script>
</center>
```

Comment: u need get current url or send request to server?

Comment: @Slaawwa  Yes. getting url like this: http://d3.xsitex.com/cgi-bin/dl.cgi/eyxjfszw64drqh3xfa7kqzntdyvjuv4fk4yoh3e7tm/url_javascr.jpg

Comment: `location.href` - take current url. But I don't understand what link u need(

Comment: thanks @Slaawwa but need click to button for this.

Comment: also sorry title would be "how to get...".

Comment: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51609188/2661164) correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

You need somethink like this I hope)

```html
http://xsitex.com/lrqpbs6uyca0/url_javascr.jpg.html

<div class="download-button-block">
    <div class="clear"></div>
     <button id="downloadbtn" class="green-button">
      <span class="btext">Download file</span>
     </button>
   </div> <!--end right column-->
  </form>

<br><center>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--<![CDATA[
/* PLACEMENT: Setup.xsitex.com.xsitex.com_980x250 */
document.querySelector('#downloadbtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(location.protocol.substr(0,4)=='http') {
        document.write(unescape('%3C')+'script id="Setup.xsitex.com.xsitex.com_980x250" src="'+location.protocol+'//lv.adocean.pl/_'+(new Date()).getTime()+'/ad.js?id=SwaXpdclN776PUuiIkkTHSZPXg_FnPrrh06YBtN1u8X.M7/x='+screen.width+'/y='+screen.height+'" type="text/javascript"'+unescape('%3E%3C')+'/script'+unescape('%3E'));
    }
})
//]]>--></script>
</center>
```

Comment: need vb.net language :)